# jquery condition checked in html and select the list based on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html based on a variable I have to decide on which list to display. How do I have the jquery condition checked in html and select the list based on the value

## html

```
<input type="hidden" id="agencyCertificationStatus" value="Pending"/> 

<script>
var agencyCertificationStatus = $("#agencyCertificationStatus").val();
</script>
```

IF STATUS IS PENDING

```
<ul>
<li>Link 1 </li>
</ul>
```

IF STATUS IS NOT PENDING

```
<ul>
<li>Link 2 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just add a class or some other identifier to the html that you want to toggle. Then, use a conditional statement in your javascript to determine which one to show.

Javascript

```
var agencyCertificationStatus = $("#agencyCertificationStatus").val();

if (agencyCertificationStatus === "pending") {
  $(".pending").show();
}
else {
  $(".not-pending").show();
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="pending status">
  <li>Link 1 </li>
</ul>
<ul class="not-pending status">
  <li>Link 2 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.status {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: this is not working as both class are already shown in the beginning. What you need is a combination of `.show()` and `.hide()` or set both class to be hidden at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

Initially hide both of the links. Then  depending on the input value show/hide the element

```js
var agencyCertificationStatus = $("#agencyCertificationStatus").val();

agencyCertificationStatus === 'PENDING' ? $('.pending').show() : $('.notPending').show()
```

```css
.pending,
.notPending {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="agencyCertificationStatus" value="Pending" />
<ul>
  <li class='pending'>Link 1 </li>
  <li class='notPending'>Link 2 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

suppose your li id is "linkLi" then you can use jquery to update the value/text inside li

```
<ul>
  <li id="linkLi"> Link </li>
</ul>


<input type="hidden" id="agencyCertificationStatus" value="Pending"/> 
<script>
var agencyCertificationStatus = $("#agencyCertificationStatus").val();
if('PENDING' == agencyCertificationStatus){
   $("#linkLi").text('Link 1')
}else {
  $("#linkLi").text('Link 2')
}

</script>
```